# "par" formatter does not retain tab indentation

Tags: text-formatting

I'm writing code in Vi and using [the `par` text formatter](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) (similar to `fmt`, but IMHO better) to format block comments.  The issue is that I can't get `par` to keep the literal tabs I use for indentation.  The formatter replaces these with spaces.

Example showing a file with initial tabs on each line and how `par` replaces these tabs with spaces.  The `cat -t` command shows literal tabs as `^I`:

```bash
$ cat -t example.txt
^I# I'd like to reflow
^I# this paragraph while retaining
^I# the initial tabs.  I don't want to end up with
^I# spaces at the start of
^I# these lines.
```

The tabs disappear:

```bash
$ par <example.txt | cat -t
        # I'd like to reflow this paragraph while retaining the initial
        # tabs.  I don't want to end up with spaces at the start of
        # these lines.
```

How can I stop `par` from replacing my indentation?

As per the suggestion in the `par` manual, I set the environment variable `PARINIT` to the cryptic string `rTbgqR B=.,?'_A_a_@ Q=_s>|`, but I haven't been able to work out whether I can modify this to get it to behave as I want.

Comment: Tab expansion can't be turned off in `par`.  It will always convert tabs to at least one space (the `T` in your PARINIT string makes it use 8 characters per tab stop).   and, yes, `par` is **much** better than `fmt`.  I've been using it since the early 90s (it's great at reformatting email with multiple levels of quoting). IIRC it was my first package for Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `par` formatter always expands tabs to spaces and can't be told to do otherwise.  The utility uses 8 spaces per tab stop when the `T` character is in the `$PARINIT` string. Instead of trying to modify the way that `par` works, the removed tab indentation may be re-inserted using [the standard `unexpand`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unexpand.html) utility:

```bash
$ par <example.txt | unexpand | cat -t
^I# I'd like to reflow this paragraph while retaining the initial
^I# tabs.  I don't want to end up with spaces at the start of
^I# these lines.
```

This also works when the original text is indented with more than a single tab.

When given no arguments, the `unexpand` utility replaces the blank characters at the start of each line with the maximum number of tabs to achieve the same visual level of indentation.  It also adds spaces after the tabs if the indentation level requires it.

From within Vi, one would use `!par|unexpand` (preceded by the appropriate addressing) to reformat the text.

Comment: +1.  Worth noting: the `T` in PARINIT assumes 8 spaces per tab stop, which matches `unexpand`'s default. See `man par` and search for "Tab" (*Tab  characters in the input are expanded to spaces, assuming tab stops every Tab columns. Must not be 0. Defaults to 1. If the T option is given without a number, the value 8 is inferred.*), and is further explained under the DETAILS heading.   Unfortunately, tab expansion can't be turned off in `par` - usually that's a feature when reformatting emails and other text, obviously not in this particular case for reformatting tab-indented code comments.

Comment: @cas Thanks! I used a short bit of that in an update to the answer. I've been using `par` for a couple of decades and prefer it for its superior handling of things like hanging indents and repeating prefix and suffix strings.